# Conditional formatting, if A2<B2 and D2<E2 on Sheet1, then cell is green on Sheet2

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do as titled.

- Product on Sheet2 will only be coloured green if both A2<B2 and D2<E2 on Sheet1.
- If one of the criteria isn't fulfilled, the product will not be green.

Here's the [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kWRZST6AGRX5jM4BvoeuIuqF_VXA7MPT2VlEmjygwmk/edit?usp=sharing).

I tried this formula, but either there's no effect, or I get an invalid code error.

```
=AND(INDIRECT("'Source Data'!A2<'Source Data'!B2","'Source Data'!D2<'Source Data'!E2")
```

Is there something wrong with the formula? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Is there something wrong with the formula?

Yes. You are using `INDIRECT` the wrong way. Please read more about [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)

**For your given data** you can use

```
=AND(INDIRECT("'Source Data'!A"&ROW()-2)<INDIRECT("'Source Data'!B"&ROW()-2), 
     INDIRECT("'Source Data'!D"&ROW()-2)<INDIRECT("'Source Data'!E"&ROW()-2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have one question: what about Product B in my example spreadsheet? It works for Product A. Does "&ROW()-2" stand for second row? I changed it to "&ROW()-3)" for Product B since the data is on the third row, but it gives me "invalid formula".

Comment: You don't have to change anything.  *"Does "&ROW()-2" stand for second row?"* No. In your test sheet, product B is next to product A. Both on row 4. If still having issues, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.